# Creating new column based on old column in query - BQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Table I have below:

```
id  | gained  | init
-----------------------
1da |   56    |  TRUE
1da |   56    |  FALSE
e4f |   23    |  TRUE
few |   23    |  TRUE
```

New column new_gained should be derived by query, Logic should be:
`CASE WHEN init is true THEN 0 ELSE gained END`

Query result I want:

```
id  | gained  | init  | new_gained
-----------------------------------
1da |   56    |  TRUE |     0
1da |   56    | FALSE |     56
e4f |   23    |  TRUE |     0
few |   23    |  TRUE |     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your issue exactly is as you have solution in your question - anyway  - below is what you asked

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1da' id, 56 gained, TRUE init UNION ALL
  SELECT '1da', 56, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 'e4f', 23, TRUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 'few', 23, TRUE 
)
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN init THEN 0 ELSE gained END AS new_gained 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Another option would be

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  IF(init, 0, gained) AS new_gained 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: which do you think is faster or more efficient?

Comment: @kudeh . . . They are the same from a performance perspective.  `CASE` is standard SQL.